# ¿Qué es una libreria en C++?

Tags: c++, ingenieria-del-software

Estoy empezando a estudiar C++ y quiero saber que es una librería en C++ en términos entendibles.

Comment: Depende de a qué te refieras con el término: algunas personas consideran que una librería es una cabecera (`archivo.hpp`) o una colección de cabeceras. Otras personas piensan que es un binario que puedes enlazar con tu programa ¿a cuál de las dos opciones te refieres? ¿o te refieres a ambas?

Comment: si puedes explícame las 2 opciones, porque la verdad soy principiante en esto.

Comment: Hola Mihawk. Ten en cuenta que aqui las preguntas buscan un trabajo de investigacion previo. Este sitio no sustituye al trabajo de un buscador web. Qué habias leido hasta el momento? qué cosas exactamente no te quedaron claras?

Comment: lo que pasa es que el profesor digamos que explica de una manera muy avanzada creyendo que nosotros somos estudiantes avanzados y a apenas vamos en 2 semestre. Aveces no entiendo los conceptos que el toca en clases un de ellos fue las librerías.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Librerías compiladas.

La explicación que buscas no difiere mucho de la que ya ofrece [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

> En informática, una librería (del inglés library) es un conjunto de implementaciones funcionales, codificadas en un lenguaje de programación, que ofrece una interfaz bien definida para la funcionalidad que se invoca.
>
> A diferencia de un programa ejecutable, el comportamiento que implementa una librería no espera ser utilizado de forma autónoma, sino que su fin es ser utilizada por otros programas, independientes y de forma simultánea. Por otra parte, el comportamiento de una biblioteca no tiene por qué diferenciarse demasiado del que pudiera especificarse en un programa. Es más, unas bibliotecas pueden requerir de otras para funcionar, pues el comportamiento que definen refina, o altera, el comportamiento de la biblioteca original; o bien la hace disponible para otra tecnología o lenguaje de programación.

En palabras más sencillas, una biblioteca o librería es un programa carente de autonomía que debe ser utilizado por otro programa, pero hay ejecutables que pueden funcionar como librería y como programa autónomo así que ¿dónde empieza una librería y dónde empieza un programa?

En C++ esta diferenciación nos la da el [punto de entrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_de_entrada_(inform%C3%A1tica)) y las funciones exportadas.

- El punto de entrdada: es donde cualquier ejecutable empezará a ejecutarse, es la función `main`.
- Las funciones exportadas: son otros puntos de entrada a un código ejecutable (la explicación es más técnica y compleja, incluso podría requerir una repsuesta diferente).

Por lo tanto podemos concluir que:

- Cuando un ejecutable tiene punto de entrada pero no exporta funciones, es un programa.
- Cuando un ejecutable tiene varias funciones exportadas pero carece de punto de entrada es una librería.
- Cuando un ejecutable tiene ambas cosas puede ser ambas cosas.

Para usar una librería de estas características, deberás enlazar su binario con tu binario. Como analogía podríamos pensar en el motor de un coche: puedes usar el motor en varios tipos coche para hacer que éstos circulen pero el motor en si no es nada sin el resto de elementos del vehículo.

#### Librerías de código.

A diferencia de las librerías compiladas, no disponen de un código binario sobre el que enlazar el programa si no que son código que debe ser compilado con el programa.

Esto hace que en ocasiones se confundan las librerías con colecciones de utilidades, y es cierto que la diferencia es muy difusa y en ocasiones más semántica que lógica. En el caso de las librerías de código, podríamos incluso llegar a decir que no son más que utilidades sueltas, no una librería en si.

Como analogía podríamos pensar en los planos de el motor de un coche: con los planos puedes construir un motor para tu vehículo.

Comment: eso era lo que quería saber, muchas gracias.